# Volume control icon no longer appears in the taskbar

Tags: windows-xp, audio

I'm having a problem with Windows XP where at some point the volume control icon stopped appearing (even if I tick the checkbox in "Sounds and Audio Devices Properties"). There is a a few knowledge base articles on similar problems:

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=319095

http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistamedia/thread/2595fb5d-5c77-4476-a762-b97654589055

But neither of those work. Has anyone had this problem and solved it?

Comment: Is your sound device driver installed?

Comment: The soundcard works (and has the right drivers), and the Volume Control application works, it's just the taskbar icon that does not appear.

Comment: Ok, did you try any of the answer I provide you?

Comment: This happens to me sometimes; on some boots, the icon just isn't there. Rebooting fixes, but is an annoying operation to perform.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue:

Click Start, click Run, type msconfig in the Open box, and then click OK.

On the Startup tab, click System Tray (SysTray.exe) so that a check mark appears next to this item.
Click OK, and then click Yes when you are prompted to restart the computer.

Comment: This may be toward the right solution, there is no value named "System Tray" under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Do you know what the data (command) for the value should be?